# Rails3 nested_form - How to display current value in edit view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created some nested form functionality using ryanb's `nested_form` gem and so far it works perfectly, but when a user edits an entry, I want to display the current value (in my case an image) that is present and allow for removing this existing entry but cannot figure out how to do that.

My code for the form so far:

```
=f.fields_for :images do |image_form|
    %p
      %label Image
      =image_form.file_field :image, :class => "form-control"
    %p=image_form.link_to_remove "<i class=\"fa fa-trash-o\"></i> Remove image".html_safe
  =f.link_to_add "<i class=\"fa fa-plus\"></i> Add image".html_safe, :images, :class => "btn btn-sm btn-default"
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to find a solution on my own (although not sure if this is the best possible way to do it):

I added a condition to check if the exiting object (in my case `@posting`) has images and then added a counter and the `image_tag`:

New code:

```
=f.fields_for :posting_images do |image_form|
  %p
    %label Image
    -if @posting.posting_images.size > 0
      -if !@posting.posting_images[@pi_count].nil?
        =image_tag @posting.posting_images[@pi_count].image, class: "img-thumbnail"
    =image_form.file_field :image, :class => "form-control"
  %p=image_form.link_to_remove "<i class=\"fa fa-trash-o\"></i> Remove image".html_safe
  -@pi_count = @pi_count + 1
=f.link_to_add "<i class=\"fa fa-plus\"></i> Add image".html_safe, :posting_images, :class => "btn btn-sm btn-default"
```

So far, it works as designed.

Notice: this is designed to work with `Paperclip`, for `Carrierwave` I guess the code looks slightly different but should be easily adaptable.